# Gitolite w. Gitweb and Wildcard Repos

Tags: gitolite, git

with a gitolite configuration like this:

```
    repo    users/CREATOR/.+
            C       =   @defaultgroup
            RW+D    =   CREATOR
            RWD     =   @defaultgroup
```

the users of our server can easily create their own repositories just by cloning the "to be created" repo - e.g. with:

```
    git clone git@git.exmaple.com/users/foo.bar/new
```

This also shows up in our gitweb. But what's missing is some git configuration. I haven't been able to figure out how I could add working configuration to these newly created repositories (e.g. gitweb.url)?

Just for comparison - this is how a "normal" repo would look like:

```
    repo    normal/repo
            R       =   @all
            RW      =   @defaultgroup
            config  gitweb.url = git@git.exmaple.com/normal/repo.git
            config  receive.denyNonFastforwards = true
```

Any hints welcome,
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [gitolite config page](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/git-config.html):

> You can also use the special values `%GL_REPO` and `%GL_CREATOR` in the string.
>   The former is available to all repos, while the latter is only available to [wild repos](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/wild.html).

So this could work (not tested):

```
config  gitweb.url = git@git.exmaple.com/%GL_CREATOR/%GL_REPO
config  receive.denyNonFastforwards = true
```

(I suppose the last line would apply to all wild repos created under `repo users/CREATOR/.+`)

Comment: Solution was right for Gitolite 3 - unfortunately version2 doesn't support equal options.